# dbGetQuery RSQlite, dificultad en código para relacionar entidades/llaves

Tags: sql, r

No estoy muy relacionado con SQL, y por temas escolares necesito aplicar la siguiente consulta (atributos necesarios en paréntesis):

*Obtener todos los MRUN (MRUN) de los alumnos que reprobaron cuarto medio (SIT_FIN="R") y se matricularon a la universidad (cod_inst=1,2,3).*

Estoy intentando con:

```
dbGetQuery(conn, '
SELECT 
distinct MRUN
FROM ed_escolar_tal_que, sit_escolar, estudia_en
WHERE situacion_escolar.RBD=educacion_escolar_tal_que.RBD
AND SIT_FIN = "R"
AND cod_inst = 1,2,3;')
```

Donde:

```
head(ed_escolar_tal_que)
  RBD     MRUN
1   1  2655917
2   1  3738782
3   1  8598804
4   1  9591749
5   1 11883473
6   1 12831468
    
head(alumnos)
  MRUN   GEN_ALU FEC_NAC_ALU
1   54         1      199603
2   65         1      200103
3   25         2      200103
4   1223       1      200105
5   254        2      200110
6   3546       2      199502

head(sit_escolar)
RBD COD_COM_RBD SIT_FIN PROM_GRAL
  <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1     1       15101 P             5  
2     1       15101 Y             0  
3     1       15101 R             4.9
4     1       15101 Y             0  
5     1       15101 Y             0  
6     1       15101 P             5.1

head(estudia_en)
  MRUN    cod_inst  ï..cat_periodo    rango_edad
1   11462      155           2020 20 a 24 aÃ±os
2   3256       143           2020 15 a 19 aÃ±os
3   62346      143           2020 15 a 19 aÃ±os
4   5724       19            2020 15 a 19 aÃ±os
5   435234     54            2020 15 a 19 aÃ±os
6   123412     143           2020 25 a 29 aÃ±os
```

El modelo que estoy utilizando es:
[image: modelo entidad-relación]

Si necesitan un reprex por favor indicar, y disculpen si no lo he puesto de inmediato. Gracias de antemano a quienes respondan.

Comment: Esto `cod_inst = 1,2,3` es erróneo, en SQL lo que estás intentando es más bien algo así `cod_inst  in (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas en tu consulta `SQL` por los cuales seguramente ni siquiera "compila" es decir funciona. Por lo que pude entender, debería ser algo así.

```
SELECT distinct A.MRUN
       FROM ed_escolar_tal_que A 
       INNER JOIN sit_escolar B
           ON B.RBD = A.RBD
       INNER JOIN estudia_en C
           ON C.MRUN = A.MRUN
       WHERE B.SIT_FIN = "R"
             AND C.cod_inst IN (1,2,3);
```

Comentarios:

- Las relaciones entre tablas deberían ser explicitas con clausulas `<tipo> JOIN <tabla> ON <Columnas`
- Cuando la consulta requiera más de una tabla es conveniente agregar alias a estas y usarlo siempre, en el código anterior indique tres alias `A, B, C` lo ideal es indicar un nombre más informativo y obviamente que sea mas corto que el nombre de la tabla.
- El tipo de `JOIN` depende de lo que se busque, yo entiendo que el `INNER` es el adecuado para este caso, mediante este solo recuperas filas que tengan coincidencias entre las dos tablas
- El filtro de multiples valores es el `IN (<valores separdos por comas>)`

**Importante**: la consulta que te he dejado es al menos sintácticamente correcta, pero no tengo forma de verificarla, para ver que funcione y que eventualmente traiga los datos que estás esperando.